# Why such code is valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
...
end
```

Why is the code in line 3 `self[column]` valid? Since `self` is an instance of `User` class, shouldn't it be self.column instead of column? I thought that `var[index]` is the way of array processing, isn't it?

Comment: Remember, `[]` is just a method.

Comment: Depends on how you interpret "line 3", but I think the relevant method here is `[]=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self[column]` is just another way of writing `self.[](column)`. where `[]` is the method name and `column` is the argument. `ActiveRecord::Base` implements `[]`, so you can access the columns like in an `Array`.

### Example:

```
class Example
  def [](arg)
    return "foo"
  end
end

x = Example.new
x[1] # => "foo"
x[3] # => "foo"
x["bar"] # => "foo"
```